# Download url chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to download a url by writing code for chrome extension. Here is the myscript.js file:

```
chrome.downloads.download(
    {url: 'http://www.iana.org/_img/iana-logo-pageheader.png',
     saveAs: true
    },
    function(res){alert(res);});
```

and here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["downloads",
    "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","d3.v2.js","myscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

but the console is showing the error  "Cannot call method 'download' of undefined".
Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for [`chrome.downloads`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html) clearly states that the "API is still under development. It is **only available for Chrome users on the dev [early release channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)**." (emphasis mine, currently at Chrome 23).

To use the API, you need to get a **dev** or **canary** build of Chrome (see [this page](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) for download links).

Another way to solve the problem is by not using the `chrome.downloads` API. I've been using the following method to create downloads, and it works like a charm (it works anywhere: Content script / background page / popup / whatever):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.iana.org/_img/iana-logo-pageheader.png';
a.download = 'iana-logo-pageheader.png'; // Filename
a.click();                               // Trigger download
```

`a.click()` causes Chrome to follow the link.
The `download` attribute causes Chrome to download the target, and suggest the attribute's value as a file name in the Save As dialog.

This feature is not limited to Chrome extensions, you can also use it in an ordinary web page. Have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dEeHF/.

Comment: Thanks..It really helped..But what to do in the case if I want to download my the files in a specific folder rather than the default Downloads folder.

Comment: @skjindal93 That's not possible using either method. That should not be a problem though: The most important things are available: 1. The file itself. 2. The file name. It's up to the user whether they place it in the default Downloads folder or elsewhere.

Comment: @RobW sorry to revive an old thread, but I just tried using your code, and it works the first time I invoke it, but then it won't work again until I restart the extension.  Can you think of why this might be happening?

Comment: @Garrett I believe that Chrome is preventing abuse by displaying an infobar which asks the user to confirm the download. However, since the background page is invisible, it appears that nothing is happening. Try running the code in a content script.

Comment: @RobW If that was the case, why would it download the first one but no others?

Comment: @Garrett Prompting to download more than one file might be abuse. If you wait a little bit, another download can be issued IIRC.

Comment: @RobW Approximately how long do I need to wait, as my extension initiates downloads generally 3-4 minutes apart?

Comment: FWIW it's 2016 I'm now running Chrome 51, and I've added `"downloads"` to my `"permissions"` list, but the debugger still shows that `chrome.downloads` is undefined.

Comment: @Dai The API is not available to content scripts.