# How to create a download link in the desktop notification window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a `contextMenu` item which sends an Ajax request to a PHP script on my website.

The PHP script creates a `.txt` file and returns the download URL to the extension again.

On the next step a `Desktop Notification` is shown and there I want to place the download link, so the user can download the created file.

The problem is that I can't use HTML there. I don't want to use `createHTMLNotification` which is deprecated, so my code is:

```
var url = 'http://mydomain.com/somefile.txt';

var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    '48.png', 'Click to download', 'Some description');

notification.addEventListener('click', function() { // can't create <a> tag, so I'm tring with a click event. 
    notification.cancel();
    window.open(url);
});

notification.show();
```

This (`window.open()`) opens the file in a new tab. But I want only to download it, without opening in the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13810026/1841048

Comment: Thank you! There is a problem with this method. A file (even different files) is downloaded only for the first time. After that it's not working until you reload the extension. But your comment sent me in the right direction and I found what I want. Here it is: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and since there are not any answers I will write it.

For downloading a file from given URL you can use the [`downloads API's download method`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#method-download):

```
function forceDownload(url) {
    var filename = url.replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, ''); // get basename

    chrome.downloads.download(
        {url: url, saveAs: true}, // options array
        function(id) {
            // callback function
        }
    );
};
```

In my situation `forceDownload()` method is called in the `Ajax' done` method:

```
function exportEntries(info, tab) { 
    var user = 'blah blah';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domain.com/export.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { topic: tab.url, user: user }
    }).done(function ( url ) {
        forceDownload(url);
    });
}
```